# Keep child toggled when clicking in search form - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a sleek responsive header for my website and use jQuery to `slideToggle` `#navSearchDD` with a search form inside from the header. The problem I'm experiencing is when I'm clicking in the search field, when it again `slideToggles` `#navSearchDD` and hides it again.

I made a JSFiddle displaying the situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/tksengen/yh8wju2q/1/

```js
jQuery(function () {

    jQuery("#navMoreButton").click(function () {
        jQuery("#navMoreDD").slideToggle("fast", function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    jQuery("#navSearchButton").click(function () {
        jQuery("#navSearchDD").slideToggle("fast", function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

});
```

```css
body { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.fs-nav-wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #22222c;
}

.fs-nav-border {
 height: 48px;
 border-top: 1px solid #333333;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    
}

.fs-nav-wrap header {
 height: 100%;
}

.fs-nav-search, .fs-nav {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.fs-nav-logo {
 width: 60%;
 float: left;
}

.fs-nav-logo {
 height: 100%;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

.nav-logo {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #F9F9F9;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
}

.nav-logo a {
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
 background-image: url('images/mobile-logo.svg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: 35px;
 
}

.fs-nav-search {
 height: 100%;
}

.fs-nav {
 height: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 
}

.fs-nav ul,
.fs-nav-search ul {
 height: 100%;
}

.fs-nav ul li,
.fs-nav-search ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 48px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
}

.fs-nav .nav-desk {
 display: none;
}

.fs-nav .nav-more,
.fs-nav-search ul li {
 margin-right: 0;
 padding: 0 20px;
 border-left: 1px solid #22222c;
 border-right: 1px solid #22222c;
}

.fs-nav .nav-more:hover,
.fs-nav-search ul li:hover {
 background-color: #15151c;
 border-left: 1px solid #333333;
 border-right: 1px solid #333333;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.fs-nav .nav-more img,
.fs-nav-search ul li img {
 width: 15px;
}

.fs-nav .nav-more {}

#navSearchDD {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 min-width: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #15151c;
 z-index: 5;
 text-align: left;
}


#navSearchDD {
    display: block;
}

#navSearchDD:after {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 width: 55px;
 background-color: #15151c;
 border-left: 1px solid #333;
 border-right: 1px solid #333;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.navSearchDD-border {
 border: 1px solid #333;
}

#navSearchDD span.screen-reader-text {
 display: none;
}

#navSearchDD input {
 background-color: inherit;
 border: none;
 color: #8c8ca4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fs-nav-wrap group">
    <div class="fs-nav-border group">
        <header>
            <div class="fs-nav-search">
                <ul>
                    <li id="navSearchButton">
                        <img src="http://fsdev.tew.no/wp-content/themes/fifasamfunnetbny/images/nav-search.svg" alt="Søk">
                        <div id="navSearchDD">
                            <div class="navSearchDD-border">
                                <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
                                    <label> <span class="screen-reader-text">Søk etter:</span>

                                        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Søk …" value="" name="s" title="Søk etter:">
                                    </label>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="fs-nav-logo">
                 <h1 class="nav-logo">
    <a href="/">Test - Hjem</a>
   </h1>

            </div>
            <div class="fs-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav-desk"><a href="#">Test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-desk"><a href="#">Test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-desk"><a href="#">Test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-desk"><a href="#">Test</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-more" id="navMoreButton">
                        <img src="http://fsdev.tew.no/wp-content/themes/fifasamfunnetbny/images/nav-more.svg" alt="Mer">
                        
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- #masthead -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- .fs-nav-wrap -->
```

How would I go about keeping `#navSearchDD` visible as I click in the search form, or is there a better way to achieve what I'm going for here?

Also, I'm not able to get `slideToggle` to work in jsFiddle if I have `display: none;` as default for some reason?

Comment: Why do you have so many nested elements? Very complex for such a simple concept :/

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Learned HTML/CSS by online guides, so it may very well be flawed. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure which elements you find redundant? fs-nav-wrap is the parent, fs-nav-border is an inset border for fs-nav-wrap, which is my preferred way of doing it at the moment. Header element is a wrapper for desktop sizes of the web page and fs-nav-search is the container div for the left floated Search button. Is the list not valid, then?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your `search-field` is inside `#navSearchDD` which is inside `navSearchButton`.

So when you click inside the search field is also detecting a click inside `#navSearchButton`.

What you can do is check for whether the click happened in the search field and if it did then do not toggle the search bar.

```
    jQuery("#navMoreButton").click(function () {
        jQuery("#navMoreDD").slideToggle("fast", function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    jQuery("#navSearchButton").click(function (event) {
        if(event["toElement"]["className"] != 'search-field') {
            jQuery("#navSearchDD").slideToggle("fast", function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        }

    });
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh8wju2q/10/

If this is not the child you were talking about you can use this method to look for a specific child and keep it from toggling.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi  VIDesignz, did you test the jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure did, in Firefox 39

Comment: I tried testing it in Firefox and you're right it isn't working there. I also tested with jsbin in Firefox which leads me to think this is a FF issue.

Comment: Hey man, here is an alternative...change the `if` comparison to `if( !jQuery(event.target).is('.search-field') ) {` and it works perfect....here is a link to the modified fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yh8wju2q/16/

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and it works. I'm not sure why my earlier solution works in chrome and not if FF, because we're essentially doing the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why setting `display:none;` is causing an issue is jsfiddle...but here is a fiddle and the code to help you out.

https://jsfiddle.net/yh8wju2q/13/

Here is a fiddle with a couple extra features
https://jsfiddle.net/yh8wju2q/14/

HTML (Simplified)

```
<div id="header">

<img id="searchButton" src="http://fsdev.tew.no/wp-content/themes/fifasamfunnetbny/images/nav-search.svg" alt="Søk"/>
<img id="menuButton" src="http://fsdev.tew.no/wp-content/themes/fifasamfunnetbny/images/nav-more.svg" alt="Mer"/>

</div>

<div id="search">
<input type="text" value="Search..."/>
</div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS (Simplified)

```
body, ul, li { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#22222c;
}

#searchButton {
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menuButton {
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#searchButton:hover, #menuButton:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}

#search, #menu {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#333333;
}

#search input {
    height:20px;
    padding:5px 0;
    text-indent:10px;
    background-color:#22222c;
    color: #8c8ca4;
    width:100%;
    border:none; outline:none;
}

#menu li {
    color: #8c8ca4;
    list-style:none;
}
```

JQuery

```
jQuery("#searchButton").click(function () {
    jQuery("#search").slideToggle("fast", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

jQuery("#menuButton").click(function () {
    jQuery("#menu").slideToggle("fast", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I can understand what you did with the HTML, but this removes the #searchButton:hover and #menuButton:hover styling when I'm actively using either #search or #menu. I figured this as an alternative, and add the hover styling from an additional tag implemented by jQuery on mouse enter, but I wasn't sure how to do this.

Comment: Also, do you know how to hide #search and #menu when you remove the mouse from these as well? I guess we're going away from slideToggle at this point. Not the biggest deal, since this is mainly for touch screens tho.

Comment: @Thomas The second fiddle in my answer takes care of keeping the hover cover on the buttons when open.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that! :)